# How to reverse the results of this procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am tring to create a simple database for a hotel. It is supposed to take care of all bookings. I am tring to make a procedure which will search for not booked rooms in given date. However, as for now my procedure can show room numbers which already have been booked at some point. Only first 5 of 20 rooms were booked so far, and they appear, the other do not.

Can anyone give me any ideas what is wrong or even better, how to make the whole procedure work?

[These are the important tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMVK0.png)

[This is the call:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPLkX.png)
The results should go all the way up to "NumerPokoju" = 20, but they stop, because they are not in the Bookings table

To clarify the question: I want the procedure to show also the rooms that simple were never booked, not only the ones that have been at least once.

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE freeRooms(IN ilosc int, IN poczatek date, IN koniec date)
BEGIN
SELECT Rooms.RoomID AS "Numer pokoju", Rooms.Places AS "Ilosc lozek"
FROM Rooms INNER JOIN Bookings ON Rooms.RoomID = Bookings.RoomID
WHERE ((poczatek < Bookings.ArrDate AND koniec < Bookings.ArrDate) OR ((poczatek > Bookings.DepDate) AND (koniec > Bookings.DepDate)))
AND ilosc <= Rooms.Places;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I hope I just added what you hoped for. If not, tell me more precisely, and I will add the required information :)

Comment: *More* precisely!?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS instead of the join:

```
SELECT 
  r.RoomID AS "Numer pokoju", 
  r.Places AS "Ilosc lozek"
FROM Rooms r
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Bookings
    WHERE 
      RoomID = r.RoomID
      AND (
        poczatek BEWEEN ArrDate AND DepDate   
        OR
        koniec BEWEEN ArrDate AND DepDate   
      )
  ) 
AND
  ilosc <= r.Places;
```

I'm not sure about the last condition: `ilosc <= r.Places` if and why you need it.

Comment: Your code pretty much opened a whole new world in front of my eyes.  
**1.** _I had no idea that when I put a letter after a full name in FROM it makes it ass a shortcut - Wow._  
**2.** _I had no damn idea such thing as EXIST exists._  
**3.** _The "ilosc <= r.Places" checks if a room is able to accomodate enought people, I think it is neccesarry, but you are definetelly the master here._
**4.** _Can you explain that does the "SELEXT 1 FROM Bookings" does?_
**5.** Most important - The procedure still shows only the rooms that exist in Bookings, the ones who don't are invisible :/

Comment: 1.It is an alias and very useful in almost all cases, 2. EXISTS and NOT EXISTS is a very efficient way to replace most conditions that need to scan a table or subquery, because it does not need to scan the whole resultset. It returns as soon as it finds an occurrence.

Comment: *The procedure still shows only the rooms that exist in Bookings, the ones who don't are invisible* for the rooms that do not exist in bookings `NOT EXISTS` **for sure** returns true, so how can they not be displayed? Did you try to remove `ilosc <= r.Places` because this is the only other condition that would affect the result.